# Refactor Custom ProblemDetailsFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

As described and documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-problemdetailsfactory), I like to customize the **ProblemDetails** hence extended **ProblemDetailsFactory** class.
However, I want to have this custom implementation to live in .Net Standard shared class library and not in the Web project itself. But I can't do that. It says that the base class **ProblemDetailsFactory** is not found.
I realized that the version of *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll* referenced in OOB web application is 3.1 whereas its 2.2.5 in my class library project.

This is what my csproj file looks like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Metadata" Version="1.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is it something doable or thought through or am I missing something here?

Comment: ProblemDetailsFactory Class only applies to asp.net core 3.0 and 3.1.Please update the version in your class library.

Comment: So instead of <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks> it should only be <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I mean that you need update the version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`.

Comment: 2.2.5 is the latest version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core which I can see in my netstandard class library project.

Comment: This was the older way of this implementation: https://stevenmaglio.blogspot.com/2019/12/create-custom-problemdetailsfactory.html

Answer (score 1):

Do not use nuget packages for aspnet stuff anymore

This works for a class library where you want aspnetcore libs available:

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```